# How do I change the direction my Cocoa window resizes in?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, interface-builder

I am trying to make it so that my main window will resize so that it expands to the right and leaves the original part in the same spot as it was before. Right now, when I click my resize button, it expands out to the left, pushing my controls out with it to make room for the new space. I would like it to expand to the right so that it will be like a slide-out window. The new space will display a saved-items ScrollView.

This is what I want to do:

```
|---------------------|

|------Original-----|

|---------------------|
```

---

```
|-----------------------------------------------|

|------Original------|  ---> New Space --|

|-----------------------------------------------|
```

---

Right now it is doing this:

```
|---------------------|

|------Original-------|

|---------------------|



|-----------------------------------------------|

|------Original-----|  <-- New Space --|

|-----------------------------------------------|
```

Pushing the Original over to the left.

(I hope this helps, it took a while)

Here is my code

```
NSRect resize;
int newWinWidth = 800;
int newWinHeight = 380;
resize = NSMakeRect([window frame].origin.x - (newWinWidth - (int)(NSWidth([window frame]))), [window frame].origin.y - (newWinHeight - (int)(NSHeight([window frame]))), newWinWidth, newWinHeight);
[window setFrame:resize display:YES animate:YES];`
```

Maybe all I need to do is change the origin of the window, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Ask anything if you need more info or something is unclear.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by “Pushing the Original over to the left”. Is it changing position? It would probably be best if you'd record a video with QuickTime Player or Screenium or ScreenFlow and post it on YouTube so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: Here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQV-JbLsntI That's probably a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you *are* changing the origin of the window. The solution is to simply not do that. Leave the origin the same and change only the size.

Window origins in AppKit are counted from the lower-left of the first screen's frame to the lower-left of the window's frame.

Comment: How would I change the code to leave the origin the same? (I'm just getting started with Cocoa)

Comment: To leave the origin the same, don't change the origin.

Comment: It would look like the code you have, except without computing different numbers for the new origin.

Comment: I got it working by doing this.  int xOrigin = [window frame].origin.x;
   int yOrigin = [window frame].origin.y;
   NSRect myRect = NSMakeRect(xOrigin,yOrigin,729,357);

Comment: Don't use `int` for coordinates (or, indeed, most things in Cocoa, CF, and Quartz). The correct type is `CGFloat`. Moreover, you could just extract the whole origin to a variable of type `NSPoint` in one assignment, and then pass the two members of that structure to your `NSMakeRect` call (or use an `NSRect` literal and pass the whole origin in the proper position in the literal).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from Interface Builder, select your control and form the Resize tab of the inspector window select the resizing properties and constraints (Interface Builder lets you see a preview of your control behaviour while the window/view it is in resizes)